# Deletion-contraction versus addition-identification

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I posted this question to [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1801643/deletion-contraction-versus-addition-identification) in 2016. No answers were forthcoming [EDIT: the question has now been answered on math.stackexchange!], even after I put a bounty on the question, so perhaps it qualifies as a research-level question.

Short version: there are two common formulas for computing the chromatic polynomial of a graph. They go by the names, deletion-contraction and addition-identification. They are equivalent, mathematically, but differ in their application. I know graphs for which a-i is more efficient than d-c. Are there graphs for which d-c is more efficient than a-i?

Long version: Let $G$ be a graph. The chromatic polynomial $P(G,k)$ gives the number of ways to color the vertices of $G$, if $k$ colors are available, and no two adjacent vertices get the same color. If $G$ is chordal (that is, if every cycle in $G$ has a chord, a pair of vertices adjacent in $G$ but not adjacent in the cycle), then you can compute $P(G,k)$ by "following your nose". If $G$ is not chordal, then you can use either of these formulas, repeatedly if necessary, to reduce to the case of chordal graphs: $$P(G,k)=P(G-e,k)-P(G/e,k)\tag1$$ $$P(G,k)=P(G+e,k)+P(G/e,k)\tag2$$ (1) is called "deletion-contraction"; $e$ is an arbitrary edge of $G$, $G-e$ is what's left when you delete $e$ from $G$, and $G/e$ is what results when you contract $e$ to a point. (2) is called "addition-identification"; $e$ is an edge not in $G$, $G+e$ is the result of adding $e$ to $G$, and $G/e$ is what happens when you identify the endpoints of $e$. (1) and (2) are mathematically equivalent, but differ in the way they are applied, as (1) deletes an edge from $G$, while (2) adds an edge to $G$.

I know examples where (2) is more efficient than (1). E.g., if $G$ is $K_{2,3}$ (each of two vertices $A,B$ joined to each of three vertices $X,Y,Z$), then any edge-deletion yields a non-chordal graph, so a second application of (1) is called for, but if $e$ in (2) joins $A$ and $B$ then $G+e$ and $G/e$ are both chordal and no further reduction is needed.

I know many examples where (1) and (2) are equally efficient (e.g., if $G$ is a 4-cycle). I don't know any example where (1) is strictly more efficient than (2) (and occasionally I think I can prove this can't happen). Is there a graph that requires fewer iterations of (1) than of (2)?

Comment: Isn't it is clear that with many vertices (1) is better for very sparse graphs and (2) is better for very dense graphs? Extreme cases are empty graph for (1) and complete graph for (2).

Comment: @Brendan, I've read assertions like that elsewhere, but never seen an example where (1) beats (2), nor a convincing argument that such exists. Cycle graphs are pretty sparse, but an $n$-cycle takes $n-3$ applications of (1) and the same number of (2), so far as I can see.

Comment: Ok, I wasn't paying enough attention to the fact that you stop when you have a chordal graph.